# Adding Quartiles when you want to break data on multiple columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote the following query to give the third quartile of patient census by Hour of day, and it works. But, I want to be able to add Day of Week, and still yield the same thing, so that I can see how the data varies by Hour and Day of Week.

Currently my results look like this:

```
Hour    3rd Quartile Census
---------------------------
0         10
1          9
2          8
3          9
4          9
...       ...
```

I would like to be able to add DOW in, so it looks like so:

```
DOW  Hour  3rd Quartile Census
------------------------------
Fri   0        9
Fri   1        9
Fri   2        8
...
Sat   0        9
Sat   1       10
Sat   2       11
...
```

I'm struggling with it because I don't think I can partition by 2 different columns?  And I don't have the right form of SQL Server 2012 to use `PERCENTILE_CONT`. Please advise.

Here is my query to aggregate Census data, and eventually add in the third quartile:

```
--Aggregated Census Table
SELECT
    [Hospital],
    [Date], [Hour],
    SUM(minutes) / 60.0 AS [patientcensus]
INTO
    #Temp
FROM
    #Observation
GROUP BY 
    [Hospital], [Date], [Hour]
ORDER BY
    [Hospital], [Date], [Hour]

--Do third quartile without DOW
SELECT [Date], [Hour], [patientcensus]
INTO #temp2
FROM #temp

SELECT 
    [Hour], [patientcensus], 
    NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY [Hour] ORDER BY [patientcensus] ASC) percentile
INTO 
    #percentiles
FROM
    #temp2
ORDER BY 
    [Hour], [patientcensus]

SELECT 
    [Hour],
    MIN(patientcensus) as '3rd Quartile Census' 
FROM
    #percentiles
WHERE 
    percentile = 75
GROUP BY 
    [Hour]
```

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @SeanLange , This is really bad post for the sake of the forums. According to the post you should use external tool in order to convert the SSMS results grid into queries, but SSMS have internal tool to present the "CREATE TABLE" (or other elements) queries! simply right click on the table name in the Object Explorer window -> select "Script Table as" -> select "CREATE To" -> and click on "New Query Editor".

It seems to me like the post focus on advertising the tool (or tutorial on using the tool) more than explaining why and what the user should provide when he ask a question in the forums

Comment: Good day sa102, as @SeanLange mentioned, please provide (1) Queries to CREATE your tables including indexes. (2) Queries  to INSERT sample data. (3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. (4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results. (5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version).

Comment: @RonenAriely on the contrary. I am NOT going to say the same explanation over and over and over. That is a very common link that people around SO use for questions in the sql server tags. That blog post talks about a number of ways to generate ddl. Is it the perfect example? No. But I am certainly not in any way shape or form trying to advertise for anything. But it doesn't seem to matter that much, the OP has vanished leaving this question pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of guess, because I haven't used the quartile function, but you mention:

> I don't think I can partition by 2 different columns

You are thinking wrong. Both the `PARTITION BY` and the `ORDER BY` parts of the `OVER` clause accept multiple arguments. Thus, try to change the second query to:

```
SELECT 
    [Date],[Hour], [patientcensus], 
    NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date],[Hour] ORDER BY [patientcensus] ASC) percentile
INTO 
    #percentiles
FROM
    #temp2
ORDER BY 
    [Date],[Hour], [patientcensus]
```